# Flyback transformer - ambiguous schematics and other issues

Tags: capacitor, transformer, driver, 555, flyback

I'm currently using this schematic for a flyback transformer:

[image: Schematic]
<sub>(source: [eleccircuit.com](http://www.eleccircuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/fly-drv2.gif))</sub>

As you can see, there's a big problem - neither the schematic, nor the website describing it, give the value of the capacitor. It says ".01", but gives no units.

http://www.eleccircuit.com/efficient-flyback-driver-circuit-by-ic-555-irf510/ Is the website. Anyone have any ideas what the unit could be? I used a 100pF capacitor in place (since I don't have a 10mF/nF/pF). I don't know if this could be a cause.

Since I don't have any 10K potentiometers, I used 2 10K resistors instead. Not sure if this could have affected it either.

I used a large steel screw (about 8mm diameter, 8cm long), wound bifilar, for the core. I do recall something about using something straight for it, maybe I'm wrong.

The only other possibilities I can think of could be poor assembly (bad soldering or unintentional shorts), defective components, or a bad schematic.

FYI, despite my tests, it hasn't worked at all (as in absolutely no arc, not just a small one, which to me suggests the type of core isn't the cause), although there is some current flowing in it since some components have heated up (but not melted).

Anyone know which of the above factors could be the problem?

Comment: The cap will probably be 10nF but the big problem on this design is the transformer - it will likely need to be ferrite cored and not a piece of steel. Also you say you wound it bifilar - this assumes you have input and output turns the same - that is not what is intended. I expect the output winding to be certainly in the order of a thousand turns in order to generate voltages anything like what the circuit diagram implies. The website you got the design from is poor in terms of information + for the unknowing, if it worked, a lethal voltage would be produced.

Comment: Will that MOSFET lead a long and happy life interrupting the current through the transformer?

Comment: Isn't that its purpose?

Comment: Whenever the units are not show, the implication is that the value is in microfarads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part of the circuit is just a simple 555 astable with variable mark/space ratio.
[image]

The capacitor, along with the resistance values sets the **frequency**. The transistor is there to drive the mosfet which simply switches the current on and off through the primary of the transformer. The transformer steps up the voltage depending on the turns ratio.

The capacitor will be .01 microfarad (or 10nF as Andy correctly gives). By using a 100pF capacitor the oscillator will run at too high a frequency (100 times more than the original design).

I also agree with Andy that the transformer (and its design/construction) is your real problem.

My real concern about this question is that if your knowledge of electronics is this limited then building this type of circuit could be fatal. High voltage is not not an area a novice should tamper with.

Comment: Thank you for the concern, but surprisingly enough (I think) I have enough experience to know fairly well what's dangerous and what isn't.
I was asking because the schematics etc seemed a little ambiguous. Also, I need to learn somehow. I figured this would be a good place to start. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: @AlexFreeman - We all have to learn (and that's a good thing) and my concern was genuinely for your well being.

Comment: @AlexFreeman  Flyback driver was my first electronics project. Playing with sparks is fun. The transistor has to be attached to a big heatsink or it will release the magic smoke a few minutes after being turned on. Also, do not try to measure the voltage of the output with a regular multimeter - you will need a new multimeter. Connecting the output (one wire, the other to ground) to an incandescent ligh bulb makes a plasma globe.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this will explain the transformer problem

[image]

The two grey blocks are the core of the transformer and in your solid steel core the top diagram applies. This solid steel core acts like a shorted turn and has big circulating currents inside of it - see red lines. In fact this is how an induction furnace works - things get hot and eventually melt. Not recommended for transformers!!

The bottom diagram shows the same core but made from several laminates. Each laminate is insulated from the others and therefore eddy currents (or induction currents) can only circulate within the thickness of each laminate. Given that the flux passing through each laminate is also much smaller (area is smaller) the net effect is a dramatic reduction in both heat and transformer inefficiency - basically is begins to work like it should. The laminate technique is usually for mains AC power transformers.

On higher frequency applications (such as yours) basic laminates are not good enough and ferrite materials are used. It's still iron plus a bunch of other materials but, by design, the electrical conductivity of the resulting material is negligible compared with steel/iron and eddy current losses can be small for frequencies in the range up to the hundreds of kHz.

Another reason why your transformer may not work properly is that the steel rod you are using doesn't form a continuous loop to hold the magnetic flux - this lowers the inductance of the coils and is unlikely to be suitable for the design proposed.

**DANGER** - if you get it working it could easily kill you if you are not careful.

Comment: That's very interesting! I had a rough idea of why laminating the core helped, but I wasn't aware it made so much of a difference. Thank you for the information.