# Building a decent 12V power supply from batteries

Tags: power, capacitor, mosfet, 555, flyback

I'm currently building a [flyback transformer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75163/flyback-transformer-construction-issues).

[image: test]

As you can see, the power supply is 12-15V, 3A. Up until now I've been using a 12VDC power supply from batteries. I guess I should have realized sooner that this would be insufficient for something requiring so much power - when online, the PD across the batteries drops to ~9V, and the current is in hundreds of milliamps. Clearly insufficient.

My question is, is it possible to somehow modify this to run on batteries? I was thinking perhaps to use capacitors to store charge to allow for a greater output current, but of course only intermittently to allow them to charge.

Since I need this to be portable, a mains-run power supply is sorta' out of the question. I'm sure there are ways round it though.

Comment: There are many kinds of batteries; you just need to choose the right kind for your application. For example, the ubiquitous 12V, 7AH rectangular lead-acid battery should be able to power your circuit for a couple of hours.

Comment: What kind of battery was being used originally? What capacity? They have 12V lithium packs that would be much smaller than a car battery alternative and probably provide you with a few hours at 300-400 mA.

Answer (score 3):

A 12v car, motorbike or even UPS battery will do fine. Hundreds of milliamps is not a lot.

Even an old scrap one that's incapable of starting a car should have more than enough oomph to power your circuit unless it's totally dead.

Comment: Wait wait, hundreds of milliamps is too small. I need about 3A to run this.

Comment: Car batteries can manage about 100A. Obviously this means an instant fire if you short it out, so add a fuse.

Comment: YOU said "hundreds of milliamps" in your original post. Car batteries can manage hundreds of AMPS. I also wonder if you are drawing more current than you need by saturating the coil, you might benefit from looking at the coil current to see if you can charge/discharge it more efficiently by changing frequency / duty-cycle.